# Ambiguous documentation for CharacterController.isGrounded

Tags: unity-game-engine, documentation

Unity's documentation for the [CharacterController "isGrounded"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-isGrounded.html) property seems ambiguous and is unclear to me.

For example let's say the CharacterController is grounded (colliding with a game object underneath it) and then Move is called (Such that it no longer collides with any game object after being moved)

Was the CharacterController touching the ground during the last move?
The documentation is ambiguous since there are two possible interpretations :

1. isGrounded depends on the CharacterController before movement is applied, so isGrounded = true.
2. isGrounded depends on the CharacterController after movement occurs, so isGrounded = false.

**Question :**

Does isGrounded depend on the CharacterController before movement is applied? or after?

Comment: I'd guess the latter ... In general couldn't you simply try this in a test scene and perform a jump? This way you see if after the call to `Move` this is true or not ...

Comment: @derHugo it seems so... I tested it out and isGrounded depends on the CharacterController after movement occurs.